# Sass Mixin: order-independent arguments without using named arguments?

Tags: css, parameters, sass, arguments

## Situation

I have a mixin like this:

```
@mixin flexbox($type: null, $direction: null) {
    @if $type == null or $type == 'flex' {
        (...)
        display: flex;
    } 
    @if $type == 'inline-flex' {
        (...)
        display: inline-flex;
    }
    @if $direction == null or $direction == 'row' {
        (...)
        flex-direction: row;
    } 
    @if $direction == 'column' {
        (...)
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

Which I can now use like so:

```
@include flexbox(inline-flex, column);
```

However I **can't** do this:

```
@include flexbox(column);
```

Because now the mixin treats the "column" as an argument for "$direction".

Is there a way around that? 
A way to make my arguments independent of their order?

E.g. I'd like to be able to use the mixin in any of these ways:

```
@include flexbox(column);

@include flexbox(column, inline-flex);

@include flexbox(row, flex);

@include flexbox(row);
```

Currently none of those are working, because of the arguments need to be in a specific order.

## Why not use named arguments?

**Update: I accept this solution as the best possible way.**

As suggested by Hashem Qolami below "named arguments" would be an option to solve this:

```
@include flexbox($direction: column);
```

This is a perfectly acceptable solution. Thanks for that.

However I'm working on a framework that will be used by multiple people in my company. 
Therefore I'd like to keep all mixins as foolproof and easy to use as possible.

In that case this:

```
@include flexbox(column);
```

Would be preferred over this:

```
@include flexbox($direction: column);
```

Because other devs know what flexbox can do, but not how I named my arguments.

It's a small thing, really. But the use of named arguments would mean that everyone would have to learn the argument-names of every mixin available.

Comment: Can't you use `@include flexbox(, column);`? Else, I would create a mixin for only direction, a mixin for only type and a mixin for both..

Comment: Thanks. Splitting up my mixins might be an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Keyboard Arguments](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#keyword-arguments)
>
> Named arguments can be passed in any order, and arguments with default
> values can be omitted. Since the named arguments are variable names,
> underscores and dashes can be used interchangeably.

Therefore you could pass the arguments as follows:

```sass
.box {
  @include flexbox($direction: row);
}
```

The output would be:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Hashem. I updated my question to further clarify the situation. But I'll go with your approach if a solution without named args is not possible.

Comment: @Arrowcatch Don't mention it. As per the update I think if you're going to build a framework all functionalities should be documented in someway than can be used by other developers. So it would be fine if you let them know what argument-names are. That's the only way I know as of now.